Private endpoint cannot use as AWS EventBridge target
I need to call an private endpoint of Springboot application (hosted in EC2) that located in my AWS VPC from an event bridge that also located in same AWS VPC.I already tried to do this using API Destination But it appears as work only with public endpoints. Also tried to do with HTTP/REST API gateways both of them do not allow to map private endpoints. Also avoiding Lambda because my private endpoint takes more than 1 minute to send the response, In this duration It would be waste of resource (As far as I know).

Disclosure: EventBridge PM here.
Yes, you're correct. API destinations today cannot target private endpoints. Please contact us through your support/account team to discuss this request further. A common workaround today is to use a Lambda function as a VPC "proxy".

I encountered this same issue.  A lambda proxy function worked, but this seems like an unnecessary step to route an event to a private API gateway endpoint.  Are there any plans on adding this functionality to EventBridge in the near future?

Thx @BrettCooper for your feedback. Yes, this is a known issue today that we want to address. I'm happy to chat and brainstorm here, so feel free to connect via your AWS team.
